A functional equation: Find all bounded functions $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(m+n)+f(m−n) = 2f(m)f(n)$, for all integers $m, n$.
The question goes as follows:
Find all bounded functions $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(m+n)+f(m−n) = 2f(m)f(n)$, for all integers $m, n$.
Here is how I started:
Putting $m=n=0$ gives $2f(0) = 2f(0)^2$, so $f(0) = 0$ or $f(0)=1$
First case: $f(0) = 0$
Putting $n=0$ in the original equation, we get:
$f(m)+f(m)=2f(m)f(0) = 0 \implies f(m)=0$ for all integers $m$
Second Case: $f(0)=1$
Putting $m=n$, we get:
$f(m+m) + f(m-m)= 2f(m)f(m) \implies f(2m) + f(0) = 2f(m)^2 \implies f(2m) = 2f(m)^2-1$
Now this is where I get stuck. I just can't proceed any further. If anyone can post the rest of it as an answer, I'll be extremely grateful. Thanks in advance!
P.S. I did check out Find all $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying: $\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$,$f(m+n)+f(m-n)=2f(m)f(n)$ but I just couldn't understand it. If anyone has a much simpler answer, that would help a lot.

Note:  the duplicate only assumes the functional equation for positive $n,m$.  Still, I suggest studying the (several) solutions posted there to see how to adapt them to this version.

The answer you linked says that the sequence $(u_n)=(f(n))$ satisfies the recursive relation
$$ u_{n+2}=2f(1)u_{n+1}-u_n $$
so we can compute $u_n$. Do you know how it's done ?

Suppose $f(0)=1$.
$f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is bounded so it has a maximum $M$ and a minimum $M'$.

Case $f(1)> 0$.

Let $m$ be an integer such that $f(m)=M$. Then $f(m-1)+f(m+1) = 2Mf(1)$. But since $f(m-1) \le M$ and $f(m+1)\le M$, this forces $f(m-1)=f(m+1)=M$ and $f(1)=1$.
Therefore the set  $\{m\in\mathbb{Z}| f(m)=M\}$ is non-empty, stable by addition by $1$ and substraction by $1$ : it's $\mathbb{Z}$ !
In other words : $f$ is constant and equal to $1$ (since $f(0)=1$).

Case where $f(1)<0$.

Then $g: m\mapsto (-1)^m f(m)$ satisfies the same equation and $g(1)=-f(1)>0$ therefore $g$ is constant equal to $1$ and $f:m\mapsto (-1)^m$.

Case where $f(1)=0$.

One checks that this forces $f(2m)=(-1)^m$ and $f(2m+1)=0$ for every integer $m$.
Conversely, $f:m\mapsto 1$, $f:m\mapsto(-1)^m$ and $f:m\mapsto (-1)^{m/2}$ if $m$ is even and $0$ otherwise. are indeed solutions.

$f(n)=(-1)^n$ is also a solution. In fact you have $f(m-1)+f(m+1)=2f(1)M$ so this works if $f(1)=1$. I really like your argument, +1.

Thanks, i've edited my answer.
